# Upload a new Firebird version into the repository. How?

Tags: 12.04, server, database

We use 25 Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS servers at our company with Firebird databases. In this release Firebird 2.5.1 is the latest version. Is there any chance somebody will update it to 2.5.2? We need this version, but our policy is to deny usage of a 3rd party repo or build it from source. So the only way is the official update. How can I help or ask for this change?

Comment: It appear all above versions of Ubuntu got the 2.5.2 update, https://launchpad.net/firebird/+packages. Not quite sure what anyone could do about it, is the update even officially supported in Ubuntu 12.04?